# Is there a way to restructure this Observable chain focus on the real data

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a way to restructure the following Obersable chain, so that subscribe will handle the real data, and the error path does not take over the main path?

That means the processing in do() should go to subscribe, filter be removed, and starting with catch reorganized to do the same thing at the end.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btnA, 'click')
  .switchMap(e => {
    let doThrow = doThrowInp.checked;
    output('Start some lengthy op' + (doThrow ? ' that fails' : ''));
    let o = Rx.Observable.of(0).delay(2000);
    if (doThrow)
      o = o.throw('Error');
    return o;
  })
  .do(data => {
    output('Got the data we are interested in: ' + data);
  })
  .filter(_ => {
    output('Stop any data propagating further down');
    return false;
  })
  .catch((err, caught) => {
    output('We catched the error, inform the user and retry click listening');
    return Rx.Observable.concat(Rx.Observable.of({}), caught);
  })
  .switchMap(x => Rx.Observable.of('hidden').delay(3000).startWith('visible'))
  .subscribe(x => {
    output('Change error message visibility: ' + x);
    errorDiv.style.visibility = x;
  }, err => {
    output("Uups, we shouldn't get here" + err);
  });
```

See all on Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/wA2H3QfTmIagwWOlG77r?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to break down a complicated observable chain into named steps, kind of 'single responsibility' applied to Rx.

Once simplified, you can re-combine, but for clarity I prefer to leave it in steps.

Live [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CbLHeodADCi105QuwNoL?p=preview)

```js
const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btnA, 'click')
const lengthyOp$ = Rx.Observable.of(0).delay(2000)

const lengthyOpWithErrorSimulator$ = 
  lengthyOp$.flatMap(x => 
    doThrowInp.checked 
      ? Rx.Observable.throw('Error') 
      : Rx.Observable.of(x)
  )

const flashError$ = Rx.Observable.of('hidden').delay(3000).startWith('visible')
  .do(x => {
    output('Change error message visibility: ' + x);
    errorDiv.style.visibility = x;
  })

click$.flatMap(_ => lengthyOpWithErrorSimulator$)
  .catch((err, caught) => {
    output('We catched the error, inform the user and retry click listening');
    flashError$.subscribe();
    return caught;
  })
  .subscribe(
    data => output('Got the data we are interested in: ' + data),
    err => output("Uups, we shouldn't get here" + err)
  )
```

Comment: You're right, it's much more readable like this. However their are two problems with it:

1) In no throw mode, clicking twice while waiting for an answer, returns the answer two times, I want the first answer be canceled and only result from second one.

2) In throw mode, when the message is displayed, clicking again results in hiding the message too early, not restarting the display time for the second error, or more likely, the hide from the first error comes through instead of being canceld.

Comment: 1) sounds like `click$.switchMap(`. 2) probably that subscribe, don't really like it. I'll take a look shortly.

Comment: I created a subject for the error handling now, see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z05rbB3nUWaxYGQIV12f?p=preview - That's working for me